# .NET Core Health Check RabbitMQ - Multiple connection nodes / cluster monitoring

Tags: rabbitmq, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to monitor the health of 2 `RabbitMQ` connections by using the Basic usage found in the documentation [HealthChecks.RabbitMq](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/tree/master/src/HealthChecks.RabbitMQ)

[image]

However, when trying to replicate a "downtime" on the second connection by stopping the service on Windows, I am greeted with both Unhealthy status despite having the **rabbitMqNode1** reachable from the Uri:

```
        {
            "Status": "Unhealthy",
            "Platform": "rabbitMqNode1",
            "Date": "2021-04-27T02:19:47.9615006+08:00",
            "Description": "None of the specified endpoints were reachable"
        },
        {
            "Status": "Unhealthy",
            "Platform": "rabbitMqNode2",
            "Date": "2021-04-27T02:19:47.9615381+08:00",
            "Description": "None of the specified endpoints were reachable"
        }
```

I already tried other connections but still getting the same result. Is this even possible with the RabbitMQ healthcheck package for multiple monitoring?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library in question, but I suspect you need to scope your dependencies. How does the DI framework know which RMQ health check gets which `IConnection` instance?

Comment: I've specified it to use a particular connection string as per their documentation. I named the nodes rabbitMqNode1 and 2 for this instance. The behavior I noticed is that if I declare 1 (healthy) after 2 (unhealthy) I will get healthy. It seems to be overriding the first declared rabbitMQ health check which is weird.
I have other health checks set up (other endpoints and sql server) and it is returning the expected behavior.

Comment: Can you try wiring everything up in their own scope? There's an AddScoped method on services, but I think you can also add a scope and in the lambda register multiple dependencies all as a group. I think the problem right now is the DI container isn't properly associating each connection with each health check, and if you think about it, it really can't. Look into scopes abs maybe lifetime scopes. You could also ask another question focused on how to register multiple groupings of services that have the same interface but need to be wired together per group.

Comment: Hi mhand, yes I already tried scoped but the DLL implementation requires it as singleton. I ended up creating my own rabbitMq health check to be registered and now it works as expected. thank you so much